# Passing multicheckbox values to another activity

Tags: android

Let me try this again with better phrasing.   I am very new at this; I am trying to pass the value result of checkbox’s to another activity.  I have tried it a few different ways without success and I would be grateful for some direction. 
I know how to make a “Toast” with the result, that is not what I want it to do.  I want the checkbox results will appear in a textview in another activity.  If someone could help me out with some hints on how to accomplish that task I would be grateful, I am sorry to bother everyone with such unchallenging questions.
 I have read a couple books and watched some tutorials but my skills are still lacking.  The books are as repetitive and  redundant as the tutorials (buttons and layouts, etc.).

```
    final CheckBox chbxshirleys = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxshirleys);
    final CheckBox chbxdianas = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxdianas);
    final CheckBox chbxzoila = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxzoila);
    final CheckBox chbxsheila = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSheila);
    final CheckBox chbxrobert = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxrobert);
    final CheckBox chbxsam = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxsam);
    final CheckBox chbxcamren = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxcamren);
    final CheckBox chbxricks = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxricks);
    final Button vendorbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vendorbutton);

    vendorbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String vendor ="";
            if (chbxshirleys.isChecked())
            {
                vendor += chbxshirleys.getText();

            }

                    if (chbxdianas.isChecked())
                    {
                vendor += chbxdianas.getText();

                    }
                    if (chbxzoila.isChecked())
                    {
                vendor += chbxzoila.getText();
                }
                    if (chbxsheila.isChecked())
                    {
                vendor += chbxsheila.getText();
                    }
                    if (chbxrobert.isChecked())
                    {
                vendor += chbxrobert.getText();
                    }
                    if (chbxsam.isChecked())
                        {
                    vendor += chbxsam.getText();
                        }
                    if (chbxcamren.isChecked())
                    {
                vendor += chbxcamren.getText();
                    }
                if (chbxricks.isChecked())
                {
            vendor += chbxricks.getText();
                }
                Intent myIntent=new Intent(getApplication(),ApplianceMessage.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxshirleys", vendor);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxdianas", vendor);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxzoila", vendor);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxsheila", vendor);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxrobert", vendor);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxsam", vendor);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxcamren", vendor);
                myIntent.putExtra("chbxricks", vendor);
                startActivity(myIntent);
        }       
        });

}
```

new activity

```
public class ApplianceMessage extends Activity {


private TextView tvname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvname);
private EditText etname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
private TextView tvcity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcity);
private EditText etcity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcity);
private TextView tvtime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
private EditText ettime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ettime);
private RadioButton rbutton =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rburgent);
private TextView tvproblem = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rburgent);
private EditText etproblem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etproblem);
private TextView tvvendor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vendorlist);
private Button msendbutton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.appliance_message);

    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    extras.getInt("chbxshirleys");
    extras.getInt("chbxdianas");
    extras.getInt("chbxzoila");
    extras.getInt("chbxshiela");
    extras.getInt("chbxrobert");
    extras.getInt("chbxcamren");
    extras.getInt("chbxsam");
    extras.getInt("chbxricks");

    msendbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    msendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tvname.setText("Insert Name");
            etname.setText("");
            tvcity.setText("City Name");
            etcity.setText("");
            tvtime.setText("Time");
            ettime.setText("");
            tvproblem.setText("Problem");
            etproblem.setText("");

    }
});

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first activity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(YourClassName.this,ApplianceMessage.class);
i.putExtra("selected",vendor);
startActivity(i);
```

In your second Activity:

```
String selecteditem=getIntent().getExtras().getString("selected");
textview.setText(selecteditem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting a String Extra in the intent. Just get it by:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("chbxshirleys");
....
```